# default value in C++ container library

Tags: c++11, containers

I saw some code

```
    unordered_map<int, int> table;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums1.size(); i++) {
        table[nums1[i]]++;
    }
```

nums1 is input vector array,   I know the value of pair is  the occurrence of entry in nums1
My question is default value of table[nums[i]] is alway 0 ?? just like default value of a local int variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) :

> operator[] is non-const because it **inserts the key if it doesn't exist**.

It inserts it by default-constructing it which, for an `int`, sets it to 0.